# Smooth random line, with loops, using Raphael/JS

Tags: javascript, drawing, raphael

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x1 = Math.random()*$(window).width(); var y1 = Math.random()*$(window).height();
    var x2 = 1; var y2 = 1;
    var paper = Raphael(document.body);

    setInterval(function() {
        randx = Math.random(); randy = Math.random();
        if (randx > 0.9) {
            if (x2 = 1) {
                if (randx > 0.99) x2 = -1;
            }
            else if (x2 = -1) {
                if (randx > 0.99) x2 = 1;
            }
        } else x2 = 0;
        if (randy > 0.9) {
            if (y2 = 1) {
                if (randy > 0.99) y2 = -1;
            }
            else if (y2 = -1) {
                if (randy > 0.99) y2 = 1;
            }
        } else y2 = 0;
        paper.path("M"+x1+" "+y1+"L"+(x1+x2)+" "+(y1+y2));
        x1 = x1+x2;
        y1 = y1+y2;
    }, 0);  
});
```

This is my "random line" generating script. I know it must look terrible, I am just learning. But I am trying to get something resembling this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Kkv.png

I'd really appreciate some tips/suggestions for the algorithm that will make the line smoother and more likely to turn do a u-turn etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to generate points within a 40x40 or so box around the previous point, and interpolate between them with a cubic spline.